# How can I expose metrics of my NodeJS service using opencensus / prometheus library?

Tags: node.js, kibana, prometheus, opencensus

My service is written using NodeJS and I want to create a separate endpoint `\metrics` that will return the following metrics:

```
Average request latency
99th percentile request latencies
```

Is there a hello world example for either *opencensus / prometheus* libraries? I didn't manage to find any examples of using it in NodeJS.

For example, when I add the following code from [this tutorial](https://gregoryguillou.github.io/gregoryguillou.github.io/2019-01/prometheus-configuration/), my output is empty even after I execute a couple of requests.

Comment: Is this not what you want?  https://opencensus.io/quickstart/nodejs/metrics/

Comment: I'm confused by this line `const stream = fs.createReadStream("./test.txt");`, don't we want just to wrap our source code with _ opencensus_ (i.e., don't create any files etc).

Comment: By the way, can I just use Setting up the NodeJS client library section from https://gregoryguillou.github.io/gregoryguillou.github.io/2019-01/prometheus-configuration/? That looks really easy to inject.

Answer (score 0):

The example you [referenced](https://opencensus.io/quickstart/nodejs/metrics/) is a good starting point.

For convenience, the example reads text from a file `./test.txt` and measure the latency in `processLine` using:

```
measure: mLatencyMs,
value: (new Date()) - startTime.getTime()
```

You want to do much the same **except** replace the file text processing with your  requests and measuring your request latencies.

There are many examples that demonstrate measuring e.g. HTTP request latencies using Express (here's [one](https://slao.io/blog/posts/request-duration/)).

So, you should combine the OpenCensus sample with code that measures and records your request latencies and, as long as you configure the Prometheus Exporter (as shown), you should be able to grab these metrics from a `/metrics` endpoint.